# get median value from a group by query in postgresql 14

Tags: postgresql

I have a query with a column as `date` type and the other as `double precision`. The `date` column is called `trading_day` and the `double precision` column is called `stock_price`. I want the median `stock_price` of every month in the year `2000`.

My query is as follows:

```
select date_trunc('month',trading_day) as dt_trunc,median(stock_price) from data_price
where extract(year from trading_day) = 2000
group by dt_trunc
```

I'm not sure if my query is really aggregating and computing correctly and I thought also that in the newer version of PostgreSQL a median function exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A standard SQL way to calculate a median is to get the continuous percentile for 50%.

```
select 
  date_trunc('month', trading_day) as dt_trunc
, percentile_cont(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY stock_price) as median
from data_price
where extract(year from trading_day) = 2000
group by dt_trunc
```

Comment: I don't understand `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY stock_price)` what is this part of the code doing? thanks

Comment: @moth Thanks.  But I don't really know either why they made the syntax for such functions that way. There are more [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-ORDEREDSET-TABLE). Maybe it's to have a distinction between a window function for records versus aggregation.